# Different orientation for PlaneBufferGeometry in chrome vs. firefox

Tags: three.js

I've created a sample to show what I'm seeing: https://haddons.net/threejs/chrome_firefox.html

I have a basic model that's loading a texture onto a plane and also pulling in some heightmap data. If I load it in chrome the texture is oriented in one direction and if I load it in firefox it's rotated 180 degrees.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a firefox, chrome or three.js bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a bug in the current version of `three.js` (`R102`). It will be fixed with the next release by this [PR](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/15904).

The problem was that textures were flipped if a resize was necessary. This always happens if you try to use mipmapping with a NPOT texture. A workaround is to configure your texture like the following, to use POT textures or WebGL 2:

```
texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
```